# Non-exhaustive patterns when I am trying to use 2 inputs of list in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
numOfSell :: Portfolio -> [StockHistory] -> Integer
numOfSell (_, h@((s, q) : _)) history = case history of
  [] -> 0
  (s, p) : _
    |(head p > last p) && (head p > mean (take 15 p)) -> floor ((integerToFloat q) / 2)
    |(head p > last p) && (head p > 2 * mean (take 20 p)) -> q
    |(head p < 1.5 * mean (take 20 p)) && (head p > 0.8 * (last p)) -> floor ((integerToFloat q) / 2)
    |otherwise           -> 0
```

When I wanted to use two lists which are h and history, it said there is non-exhaustive part in my function. I have no idea why that happened and how to solve it.

Comment: Cannot reproduce as given. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What if the portfolio is `(...,[])`? Why are you matching on `s` twice, in the function definition and case? I'd turn on the warnings with `-Wall`: GHC will spot these mistakes and report them.